# Syntax error while using Lambda functions

Tags: python, filter, lambda

I have a list with some dummy email address as below:

```
listEmails = ['brian-23@email.com', 'britts_54@email.com', 'lara$@email.com']
```

I was trying to use `lambda` and `filter` to get the list of valid email address.
let's assume `lara$@email.com` is the only invalid email address.

I used the regular expression to filter out the invalid emails using the below code.

```
listValid = list(filter(lambda x: x if re.match(r"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{0,3}$",x) ,listEmails))
```

I have been receiving a syntax error at `,` before `listEmails))`.

Generally, the `lambda` function takes the value after the comma(`,`) as the **input value**, so I am not sure if the `lambda` function is assuming `x` from `re.match(r"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{0,3}$",x)` as the input value.

Lambda function with `if` conditions are possible from the below case:

```
from functools import reduce
f = lambda a,b: a if (a > b) else b
reduce(f, [47,11,42,102,13])
```

So, I wanted to know why it isn't working in my case?

Note: Since I got an error at the `lambda` function itself, I haven't evaluated if the `list(filter(` would return the desired result.

Comment: re.match will be None for a non match so you don't need any if

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing an *`else`* clause in the conditional expression:

```
x if re.match(...) else None
```

You cannot just use the `if` on its own; all expressions always produce a result, so if the `re.match()` returns `None`, you need to decide what should be returned *instead*.

You don't need a conditional expression here at all, just return the result of the `re.match()` call:

```
listValid = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(r"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{0,3}$", x), listEmails))
```

In Python 3, it is often easier to just use a list comprehension instead of `filter()`:

```
listValid = [x for x in listEmails if re.match(r"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{0,3}$", x)]
```

I'd store the compiled regular expression in a separate variable to make that a little more readable:

```
email_test = re.compile(r"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{0,3}$")
listValid = [x for x in listEmails if email_test.match(x)]
```

Comment: I tried `else pass` and since that didn't work, thought `else` wasn't the cause. My bad. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Instead of `pass` use a value

Comment: `else: pass` is almost as good as not writing `else:` part itself.

Comment: @Vaulstein: `pass` is not an expression, it is a statement. You can only use expressions in `lambda`. `pass` means *do nothing*, while you *have* to do something instead. `None` would be a suitable object to return instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `else` part in your ternary expression.

As you stated:

```
a if a > b else b
```